# Why do I get a NamingContextPackage.NotFound exception?

Tags: java, corba

I'm new in CORBA. When I run the below code, I'm getting:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound:
>   IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0

in line:

```
ncRef.rebind(factoryName,  rootpoa.servant_to_reference(sessionFactoryServant));
```

**Code:**

```
final String initHost = System.getProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost",
        java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(initHost) == true)
    {
        properties.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", initHost);
    }

    //final String initPort = System.getProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort");
    final String initPort = "1051";
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(initPort) == true)
    {
        properties.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", initPort);
    }

    // Start the ORB.
    m_orb = ORB.init(m_arguments, properties);

    POA rootpoa = POAHelper.narrow(m_orb.resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
    rootpoa.the_POAManager().activate();

    final RSSessionFactoryServant sessionFactoryServant = new RSSessionFactoryServant(rootpoa);
    rootpoa.activate_object(sessionFactoryServant);


    org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = m_orb
            .resolve_initial_references("NameService");
    System.out.println("Name server is " + objRef + ".");

    NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);
    System.out.println("Naming context is " + ncRef + ".");

    final NameComponent[] factoryName = getSessionFactory();    // Contains name components.. nothinf seems wrong here 
    System.out.println("Session Factory is [" + ArrayUtils.toString(factoryName) + "].");

    ncRef.rebind(factoryName,  rootpoa.servant_to_reference(sessionFactoryServant));

    System.out.println("Server ready and waiting ...");

     m_orb.run();
```

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: You may have to use - ncRef.resolve(factoryName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you are searching for is not known to the Naming Service. Therefor you're getting NotFound exceptions. You may want to use `bind` in the first step.

[Oracle Doc for NamingContextOperations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CosNaming/NamingContextOperations.html#rebind%28org.omg.CosNaming.NameComponent[],%20org.omg.CORBA.Object%29)

Comment: Link fixed to Java 7 doc